# if else if else statements (JS)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, math

I'm having a problem with my program. First, I'll tell you what it's meant to do:
It is supposed to do the Pythagorean Theorem for you. [Theorem Explanation Here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=pythagorean&oq=pyth&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59l2j0l3.4407j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Here is the Mathematical Formula: (a * a) + (b * b) = (c * c)

Here is the Program:

```
function pythagorean (a, b, c) {
if (c === null){
    return 'c = ' + Math.sqrt( (a*a) + (b*b) );
} else if (b === null) {
    return 'b = ' + Math.sqrt( (c*c) - (a*a) );
} else if (a === null) {
    return 'a = ' + Math.sqrt( (c*c) - (b*b) );
} else {
    return "I'm sorry, I don't understand."
};
};
```

I decided to be fancy and try to make it so that if both sides: A and B were null, the program would assume a === b, and it the formula would become: *[Whatever C Is]* c = Math.sqrt(2 * ( (a * a) + (b * b) ) )

(Sorry its confusing)

So I tried implementing some code to make it work:

```
function pythagorean (a, b, c) {
if (c === null){
    return 'c = ' + Math.sqrt( (a*a) + (b*b) );
 } else if (a && b === null){
    return 'if a and b are equal, then a and b both equal ' + Math.sqrt((c * c) / 2);
 } else if (b === null) {
    return 'b = ' + Math.sqrt( (c*c) - (a*a) );
 } else if (a === null) {
    return 'a = ' + Math.sqrt( (c*c) - (b*b) );
 } else {
    return "I'm sorry, I don't understand."
 };
};
```

But whenever I give C a value, but both a & b === null, it weirdly just skips that else if statement and goes down to the b === null else if statement and gives me: 'b = ' and some random answer. I need your guys' / girls' help!

Comment: It'll be easier if (now or next time) you could turn it into runnable code either through jsfiddle or through stackoverflow (click the 5th button, from the left, on the second column).

Comment: `a && b === null` doesn't do what you think it does. It checks whether `a` is true and `b === null` is true.

Comment: a === null && b === null. You have to check each separately.

Comment: Should be `a === null && b === null`

Comment: Why you use `a` and `b` skipping? Use `b` and `c`, and check they are `undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: Clearly I should have seen the obvious mistake, thanks to all of you guys for helping!!

Comment: for if(a === null)  you can try if (!a)  this will make it easy and simple.

Comment: try this: if(!a && !b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (a && b === null)` is not the correct way to check if they're both `null`, the effect of it is to check if `a` is *truthy* and `b` is `null`, effectively:

```
if ((a) && (b === null))
```

You should instead use something like:

```
if ((a === null) && (b === null))
```

---

That's the solution to your immediate problem but, if you're looking for a solution that handles all errant cases (such as one of the sides being `null` when the hypotenuse is also null), you may be better off expanding on your checks a little. You may think this would complicate the code but you can also simplify things greatly by knowing situations made impossible by previous checks.

Since I'm not really a big fan of the `if (something) return else` paradigm (the `else` is always superfluous in that case), I've removed them. I also tend to prefer slightly more meaningful variable names.

The code below incorporates all those changes and adds comments explaining each section:

```
// pythagorean:
//    Returns string indicating "missing" info for a 
//    right-angled triangle (two regular sides and the
//    hypotenuse). Basic outcome is:
//        Hypotenuse null, sides given, return hypotenuse.
//        Sides null, hypotenuse given, return equal sides.
//        Hypotenuse and only one side given, return other side.
//        Anything else, error given.

function pythagorean (s1, s2, hyp) {
    // At least one value must be null.

    if ((hyp !== null) && (s1 !== null) && (s2 !== null)) {
        return "ERROR: all fields given, don't know what you want";
    }

    // If hypotenuse is null, need both other sides or error.
    // Returns hypotenuse.

    if (hyp === null) {
        if ((s1 === null) || (s2 === null)) {
            return "ERROR: hypotenuse is null, other sides cannot be";
        }
        return "hypotenuse is " + Math.sqrt((s1 * s1) + (s2 * s2));
    }

    // At this point, we KNOW we have hypotenuse, don't check again.
    // If BOTH sides are missing, assume equal.

    if ((s1 === null) && (s2 === null)) {
        return "sides are both " + Math.sqrt((hyp * hyp) / 2);
    }

    // At this point, we have hypotenuse and exactly one side
    // (not the other), so just return the other side.

    if (s1 === null) {
        return "side 1 is " + Math.sqrt((hyp * hyp) - (s2 * s2));
    }
    return "side 2 is " + Math.sqrt((hyp * hyp) - (s1 * s1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional operator should be like this

**a === null && b === null**

As it will check a is null and b is also null.

**a && b === null**

above condition will check whether a has some value (eg. 1) should not be "0" and null, NaN, '' and "" and b is null.

```js
   function pythagorean (a, b, c) {
if (c === null){
return 'c = ' + Math.sqrt( (a*a) + (b*b) );
 } else if (a === null && b === null){
return 'if a and b are equal, then a and b both equal ' + Math.sqrt((c * c) / 2);
 } else if (b === null) {
return 'b = ' + Math.sqrt( (c*c) - (a*a) );
 } else if (a === null) {
return 'a = ' + Math.sqrt( (c*c) - (b*b) );
 } else {
return "I'm sorry, I don't understand."
 };
};

var abc = pythagorean(null,null,2);
alert(abc);
```

Comment: "some value"? You mean, like 0 or ""? :-) I think the phrase you're looking for is "truthy".

Comment: @paxdiablo No. It should  True Value.

Comment: I think you'll find `0`, `false`, `null`, `NaN`, `''` and `""` are all values as well.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for correcting me. I just updated my ans

Answer (score 0):

this one looks correct

```
 else if (a==0&b==0)
```